# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-services, tomcat

So I am trying to make a very simple Web Service using Tomcat and Maven on Eclipse. I added these dependencies in pom.xml:

```
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

I just added this to my default web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And I'm just trying to get a simple string:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("car")
public class Car {

    @GET
    @Path("carName")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String carName() {
        return "Subaru";
    }
}
```

Console log:

```
SEVERE: Servlet [jersey-servlet] in web application [/WebService01] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1042)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5180)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    ...
```

[image]

Running on macCatalina 10.15.4

Comment: Tomcat running (catalina logs)? The web app started without errors (app logs)?

Comment: @Serge thx for your reply. I saw an error message on log and corrected it by just editing a space on web.xml. But now I got another error as shown in my edited answer. Thx in advance.

Comment: What's under that Root Cause text?

Comment: @nitind thx for your reply, I edited my question.

Comment: What Java compliance are you compiling to? That (old) version of Jersey was from 2015, it's reading class files, and presumably anything newer than Java 8 might cause it problems.

Comment: @nitind I changed the jersey to [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/3.0.0-M1). See new edited question. Thx in advance.

Comment: Deployment is worth checking. Is the jersey-client jar included in the lib directory (of the dynamic web project in Eclipse or the unzipped war file in Tomcat)?

Comment: And do you need a `jersey-server` artifact instead of the `jersey-client`?

Comment: I changed the artifact to jersey-server too and same error still :/ @nitind

Comment: In my lib directory I do have the Apache Tomcat v9.0 and now both jersey-client-3.0.0-M1.jar and jersey-server-3.0.0-M1.jar inside Maven Dependencies. @Serge

Comment: Which artifact and jar has that class?

Comment: What do you mean? How can I verify that? @nitind

Answer (score 0):

How about adding to pom.xml jersey-container-servlet-core, which contains the missing container class?

```
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/3.0.0-M1